# Creating Databricks clusters, notebooks, jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I have written the code to create Databricks workspace with terrafom.I am using AWS. I ran the code for workspace, I have both databricks worspace url and token. Now I want to use these to create clusters, notebooks, jobs. I am following [Create clusters, notebooks, and jobs with Terraform](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/terraform/cluster-notebook-job.html) this. I can only see that the configuration to initialize and authenticate the terraform with the workspace is through "Databricks CLI configuration profile" and through "authenticate with environment variables". Insted I would like to pass the url and token as variables in my variables.tf file. How can I do it?

I am only getting started. I couldnt find a way to pass url and token as variables.
And also I am trying to integrate these clusters, notebooks, jobs with my existing databricks workspace code. I want to create the workspace first and then I want the outputs of it, in this case usl and token. I want to pass them to some other file so that those can be used to create clusters, notebooks, jobs etc.

Comment: Even though you have given a solid description of the problem, without any code it is really hard to tell. Based on what you have written, I would say you probably want to use terraform outputs and then reference them wherever you need (if you are using modules). If you are not using modules, you should be able to use implicit references within the same root module.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Terraform provider supports [different authentication methods](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authentication), including using Databricks CLI profiles, explicit URL/Token, ... Parameters could be specified either in the `provider` block, or as environment variables.

For you case, here is an example from the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-hostname-and-token):

```
provider "databricks" {
  host  = "https://abc-cdef-ghi.cloud.databricks.com"
  token = "dapitokenhere"
}
```

that could be easily adapted to use data from variables (similar to an example with user/name password later in the doc). It's standard Terraform functionality, not specific to the Databricks provider:

```
variable "databricks_host" {
  type = string
}

variable "databricks_token" {
  type = string
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = var.databricks_host
  token = var.databricks_token
}
```

and then in `terraform.tfvars`:

```
databricks_host  = "https://abc-cdef-ghi.cloud.databricks.com"
databricks_token = "dapitokenhere"
```